# JSON dump in Python writing newline character and carriage returns in file.

Tags: python, json

When I open and write a valid json into a file with the command below, it writes newline and carriage return characters into the data.

```
with open('logs/output.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(json_data, outfile, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
```

output.json looks something like this:

```
{\r\n \"config\": {\r\n \"app\": {\r\n \"calendar\": {\r\n \"{tenant-key}calendar.reference }
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I've seen something like this before when converting a json string to json. What is the type of json_data?

Comment: How can you prevent *what* exactly? What would the expected output be?

Comment: Carriage returns are valid according to the JSON spec. Why do you want to disable this default and generally valid behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

```
json.dump(json_data, outfile, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Indent keywords argument needed only if you want indents on your new lines. You're activating "pretty print" by doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I got something similar to work by doing something like this:

```
newJson = json.dump(json_data, outfile, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
with open('logs/output.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(newJson)
```